# Table of contents page numbers not displayed in right color

Tags: table-of-contents, pagecolor

My page background is dark blue, and the text is white so it can be seen on the dark background. For some reason, the white text is not applied (they are still black, and hence not visible) to some of the page numbers in the table of contents. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Oooo, interesting. Can you provide a minimal example that replicates this behaviour? Something we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing? The code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Answer (score 2):

If the text of the whole document should be white, use `\color{white}` *in* the preamble:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{blue!20!black}
\color{white}% <- change the color in the preamble
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you want to change the color in the document, load package `normalcolor` and add use `\resetnormalcolor` next to `\color{white}`:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{blue!20!black}
\usepackage{normalcolor}
\begin{document}
\color{white}\resetnormalcolor
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\color{green}\resetnormalcolor
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the color of the page number in footer has been changed, too.